# Create a tekst marker with border radius don't work

Tags: html, css, google-maps-markers, quote

Is there anyone who can help?

I have to make some kind of quote, with a marker behind it.

What doesn't work is that if the text 'breaks' the border radius goes around each paragraph of the text.

I have tried everything via codepen. But unfortunately nothing works yet.

You can go to the codepen via the link. Here you can see what it should be. ONLY that border radius may not be interrupted. Everything must be round. There should be no corners, as there are now

If anyone can help please?

[tekst marker](https://codepen.io/stephaniemeys/pen/NWoQzpw)

```css
p span {
  padding: 7px;
  line-height: 35px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque cmauris </span></p>
```

Comment: We do require that your (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code is here in your question, not hosted elsewhere (a live demo elsewhere is often a great bonus, but it doesn't replace the need to have the (relevant) code in your question). Please read the previous link (to a page in [SO]'s help section), along with the guidelines on "*[ask]*."

Comment: Tekst  - Text, test?

Comment: @DavidThomas The code and link are visible now

Comment: @LeeTaylor The code and link are visible now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `box-decoration-break:clone` is built for this. Note that you would need the `-webkit` prefix for [many major broswers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break#browser_compatibility).

```css
p span {
  padding: 7px;
  line-height: 35px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque cmauris </span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks @SyndRain ! This was exact where I was looking for!